# How to calculate the next?

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, floyd-warshall

So I am implementing the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. On each "Ex", some code is missing but I filled them all in. The code is still incorrect and I do not know why.

If the adjacency matrix is not infinity then the `next[i,j]` should be `j`?

```
/// <summary>
/// EXERCISE 5: Floyd-Warshall Algorithm
/// </summary>
///
/// <param name="adjacencyMatrix">the adjacency matrix representing the graph</param>
/// <returns>a tuple containing 1. the distance matrix, 2. the next matrix</returns>
static Tuple<double[,], int[,]> FloydWarshall(double[,] adjacencyMatrix)
{
  var numVertices = adjacencyMatrix.GetLength(0);

  double[,] dist = new double[numVertices, numVertices];

  int[,] next = new int[numVertices, numVertices];

  for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
    {
      if (i == j)
      {
        // TODO: Ex5.1; dist[i, j] = ?

        dist[i, j] = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        // TODO: EX5.2; dist[i, j] = ?

        dist[i, j] = adjacencyMatrix[i,j];
      }

      if (adjacencyMatrix[i, j] != Double.PositiveInfinity)
      {
        // TODO: Ex5.3; next[i, j] = ?

        next[i, j] = j;
      }
      else
      {
        next[i, j] = -1;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int k = 0; k < numVertices; k++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
      {
        //if (? < ?) { ... }
        // TODO: Ex5.4
        if (dist[i, k] + dist[k, j] < dist[i, j])
        {
          dist[i, j] = dist[i, k] + dist[k, j];
          next[i, j] = next[i, k];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return new Tuple<double[,], int[,]>(dist, next);
}
```

Comment: Please review this thread as it might help you to solve this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floyd-warshall-algorithm-dp-16/

Comment: You should implement this as a recursive algorithm.   You have three nested for loops which limits the algorithm to N=3.

Comment: Looks right to me at first glance. Don't you have any feedback on why it's wrong? Is it the distances or the next matrix or both? Can you work through those examples by hand?

Comment: @jdweng I don't follow - what's N here? The k loop should complete the whole graph, shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually maybe you need to check for Double.PositiveInfinity in dist[i,k] and dist[k,j] in Ex5.4 and skip this comparison if there are infinities there.

Comment: See wiki (which uses k instead of N) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: @jdweng and this code uses k in the same sense as the wiki does, and the pseudocode there just uses three nested loops.

Comment: Will only work when max length is 3.  Do you want to have 10 nested for loops when K = 10?

Comment: Rubbish. There's nothing in Wikipedia that says this algorithm has exponential complexity. In fact it says "The modern formulation of the algorithm as three nested for-loops ..." and "It is able to do this with Theta(V^3) comparisons". Explain to me why you need more than one pass for intermediate nodes?